# Drop down menu toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm making a site that's responsive. When the page is <=830px the look of the page changes.

I need help figuring out a way to toggle the sub menus one at a time. Wordpress generates the same .sub-menu class name for each submenu.

I'm using this code to toggle the menus but they both go at the same time.
You will need to make the browser less than 830px to see what I'm talking about.

```
$(".about").click(function() {
    $(".sub-menu").slideToggle("fast");         
    return false;
}); //.click

$(".projects").click(function() {
    $(".sub-menu").slideToggle("fast");         
    return false;
}); //.click
```

Thank you for your help.

[http://www.mackeyshotrods.com/store/?page_id=2](http://www.mackeyshotrods.com/store/?page%5fid=2)

Comment: Forgot to include the link http://www.mackeyshotrods.com/store/?page_id=2

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#na ul li").click(function () {
         $(this).siblings().find('ul').slideUp(400);
            $(this).find('ul').slideToggle('fast');         
    });
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/7P3Df/1/

Comment: This works but when the link is clicked it takes me to the about page instead of dropping down the list and staying on the current page. Do you have a fix?

Comment: `$("#menu-menu-1 li").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().find('ul.sub-menu').slideUp('fast');
    $(this).find('ul.sub-menu').slideToggle('fast'); 
    return false;        
   });
     
`

Comment: The above code is doing what I want it to do but the links don't work now. I need the about link to toggle not link to the about category. The sub-menu links need to link to the posts.

Comment: When I remove the return false; all the links work but i don't want the about or projects link to open a new page when clicked.

Comment: @ijustchill, If you set return false in your code, the page did not postback. Can you please explain clearly what you want?

Comment: The links are not working on the drop downs when the browser Window is less than 800px.  When I click about link I would like the drop down to appear and then be able to click a sub mrnu link from the drop down.  Right now the links don't work.  If I remove return false; the links work but when I click about it takes me to the about page instead of just dropping down the sub menu.  Hope that all makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `$(".sub-menu").slideToggle("fast");` it applies to all the element which have the `sub-menu` class. To apply it only to the *current* element, call your method on `$(this)`:

```
     $(".about").click(function() {
        $(this).slideToggle("fast");         
        return false;
    }); //.click

    $(".projects").click(function() {
        $(this).slideToggle("fast");         
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than handling individual clicks you can use the following code

> $(".menu-item").click(function(){
>       $(".sub-menu", $this).slideToggle("fast");
>   };